# JSF Managed Bean Method for actionListener does not have property?

Tags: glassfish-3, managed-bean, jsf-2.2

I know this question is out there a lot, but after reading most of the answers and suggestions I believe I may have strayed from the proper path. Currently the error I am getting is the Following

/categorias.xhtml: The class 'Vista.CategoriaBean' does not have the property 'getcategoriaIDFromCat'.

Stack Trace

javax.el.ELException: /categorias.xhtml: The class 'Vista.CategoriaBean' does not have the property 'getcategoriaIDFromCat'.

I am checking back with JEE as I have not used it in over a year but do not recall how to resolve this error.

I am using JSF 2.2 and have a page given the following:

```xhtml
<ui:repeat value="#{categoriaBean.lista}" var="test">
   <article class="row">
        <div class="col col-md-12">
            <img src="images/Category/#{test.categorianame}.jpg" 
                alt="#{test.categorianame}" class="img-thumbnail img-responsive img_left"/>
            <h4>
                <h:outputText value="#{test.categorianame}"/>
            </h4> 
            <p>     
                <h:outputText value="#{test.categoriadesc}"/>
            </p>
            <h:form>
                <p>
                    <h:commandButton action="negociosByCat.xhtml" immediate="true" 
                        actionListener="#{categoriaBean.getcategoriaIDFromCat}" 
                        class="btn btn-primary" role="button" 
                        value="Ver #{test.categorianame}"/>
                </p>
            </h:form>
        </div>                                          
    </article>
</ui:repeat>
```

And where the Managed bean is (sorry for the whole class being pasted by I suspect the issue is here):

```java
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class CategoriaBean implements Serializable{
@EJB
private NegiciosBLLocal negociosBL;
@EJB
private CategoriaBLLocal categoriaBL;

int categoriaID;
Categoria categoria;
List <Categoria> listaCategoria;
List <Negocios>  listaNegocios;

public Categoria getCategoria() {
    return categoria;
}

public void setCategoria(Categoria categoria) {
    this.categoria = categoria;
}

public NegiciosBLLocal getNegociosBL() {
    return negociosBL;
}

public void setNegociosBL(NegiciosBLLocal negociosBL) {
    this.negociosBL = negociosBL;
}

public CategoriaBLLocal getCategoriaBL() {
    return categoriaBL;
}

public void setCategoriaBL(CategoriaBLLocal categoriaBL) {
    this.categoriaBL = categoriaBL;
}

public int getCategoriaID() {
    return categoriaID;
}

public void setCategoriaID(int categoriaID) {
    this.categoriaID = categoriaID;
}

public List<Categoria> getListaCategoria() {
    return listaCategoria;
}

public void setListaCategoria(List<Categoria> listaCategoria) {
    this.listaCategoria = listaCategoria;
}

public List<Negocios> getListaNegocios() {
    return listaNegocios;
}

public void setListaNegocios(List<Negocios> listaNegocios) {
    this.listaNegocios = listaNegocios;
}

public CategoriaBean() {categoria=new Categoria();}

public List<Categoria> getLista(){
listaCategoria = categoriaBL.getCategorias();
return listaCategoria;
}

public void getcategoriaIDFromCat (ActionEvent evento){
categoria = listaCategoria.get(Integer.parseInt(evento.getComponent().getClientId().split(":")[1]));
categoriaID=categoria.getCategoriaID();
}

public List<Negocios> getNegociosByCategory(){
listaNegocios = negociosBL.getNegociosByCat(categoriaID);
return listaNegocios;
}

}
```

When I run this in Glassfish 3.1.2.2 (build 5), can anybody assist?

Comment: Why do you use a getter method for your action listener? Getter methods are designed to get property values, not to perform action logic as you're doing here. Wrap everything in an `action` method.

Comment: Thanks, I will try that, I added the get just finally messing around with the code, the actual name of the method was prepare. I will try that and update.

Comment: Reviewing your answer more clearly now I need the actionListener so I can capture the following no?

categoria = listaCategoria.get(Integer.parseInt(evento.getComponent().getClientId().split(":")[1]));

Comment: Have you thought about sending parameters with command button's POST request? I think you're making it so difficult cause you aren't using JSF capabilities properly. Think also about the correctness of having a session scoped bean in this case. IMO two different view scoped beans would suit it more properly, one for the list and for detail the other.

Comment: Thanks Extreme Biker I left the old method and opted for f:parameter, thanks for help!